# Работа метода map JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Кому не трудно, поделитесь знаниями пожалуйста. Обескураживает работа метода map().
Вот к примеру массив - `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
К примеру замена нулями `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map(v=>0)` консоль выведет `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
Но если каждый элемент гнать через условие, что каждый четный = 0,  `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map((v,i)=>{i%2?0:v})` консоль сообщает, что элементы не определены `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`
При этом с коллекцией, приведенной методом к массиву, проблем не возникает. Я чет потерялся :)

```js
text.innerHTML=text.innerHTML.split('').map((v,i) => (i%2) ? `<font color="red">${v}</font>` : v).join('');
```

```html
<span id="text">MyText</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В выражении

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map((v,i)=>{i%2?0:v})
```

Достаточно заменить фигурные скобочки на круглые. Вот так:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map((v,i)=>(i%2?0:v))
```

---

**Что это за магия?!**

Использование в стрелочной функции после знака `=>` открывающей фигурной скобки предполагает, что вы будете использовать *блок операторов*, совсем как в обычной функции. При этом, для того чтобы что-то вернуть из функции, вам в явном виде нужно использовать конструкцию `return`. Например так:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map((v,i) => {return i%2?0:v})
```

Вместе с этим, в JavaScript существует еще один формат записи стрелочной функции, когда вместо тела функции, вы используете некоторое выражение. В этом варианте, конструкция `return` и границы блока операторов (те самые обрамляющие фигурные скобки) должны быть опущены. Это очень удобно для коротких анонимных функций, чей задаче является преобразовать одно значения в другое. Например:

```
const plusOne = x => x + 1;
const moreThanFive = x => x > 5;
const negate = x => -1 * x;
const id = x => x;
const compose = f => g => x => f(g(x));
```

<sub>Очень напоминает Haskell, правда? :)</sub>

Конструкция

```
(v,i) => (i%2?0:v)
```

это всего лишь второй способ использования стрелочной функции, где результат обрамлен в круглые скобочки. Они не меняют результата, просто делают код более читаемым. Строго говоря, эти скобки не являются обязательными и вы можете записать исходный кусочек кода вот так:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map((v,i) => i%2?0:v)
```

Comment: Дмитрий, прошу Вас объяснить мне этот синтаксис `()=>()`

Comment: В процессе дополнения ответа  :)

Comment: Дмитрий, поклон Вам до земли.